# Update API Server pods when more than 1 masters

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl

I have installed a kubernetes cluster of 10 nodes(2 masters, 3 etcds, 5 minions) using Kubespray. Presently my cluster supports Token based authentication. I want to add Basic-Auth capability as well.
I couldn't find any higher level resource than Pod in kube-system namespace. So tried manually updating the pod. Added **known_users.csv** in specified location and updated **kube-apiserver.manifest** file in one of master nodes and tried updating the pod using **kubectl apply**, which resulted in that master node going offline.

Is there a way to update this config after deploying cluster, as i don't want to re-spin whole cluster just to enable this?

[Related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41566408/restart-kubernetes-api-server-with-different-options)